# Is there is a way to mask sprites in Spriter?

Tags: sprites

I am very new to **Spriter**. I want a sprite to be only displayed when it is above particular sprite.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, spriter has no masking.
Back in 2013 it was said to be in consideration for future and in 2016 it was said that "There is no masking feature in Spriter" so either they decided not to implement it or it's still up for consideration.

https://steamcommunity.com/app/332360/discussions/0/208684375410361282/
https://brashmonkey.com/forum/index.php?/topic/3131-masking/